# How to handle third party application logout

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, identityserver4

I have an Identity server running Identity server 4.  The logout code is similar to what they recommend in their [sample project](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI/blob/master/Quickstart/Account/AccountController.cs#L195).

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Logout(LogoutInputModel model)
    {
        // build a model so the logged out page knows what to display
        var vm = await BuildLoggedOutViewModelAsync(model.LogoutId);

        if (User?.Identity.IsAuthenticated == true)
        {
            // delete local authentication cookie
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync();

            // raise the logout event
            await _events.RaiseAsync(new UserLogoutSuccessEvent(User.GetSubjectId(), User.GetDisplayName()));
        }

        // check if we need to trigger sign-out at an upstream identity provider
        if (vm.TriggerExternalSignout)
        {
            // build a return URL so the upstream provider will redirect back
            // to us after the user has logged out. this allows us to then
            // complete our single sign-out processing.
            string url = Url.Action("Logout", new { logoutId = vm.LogoutId });

            // this triggers a redirect to the external provider for sign-out
            return SignOut(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = url }, vm.ExternalAuthenticationScheme);
        }

        return View("LoggedOut", vm);
    }
```

What the above code does is when it gets preform a logout by deleteing the login cookie on the identity server.

```
await HttpContext.SignOutAsync();
```

This all makes perfect sence.  On the identity server.  Someone calls logout and its logged out.

**Third Party applications**

My issues is with third party applications.  When our third party applications call logout they call the identity server and it deletes the cookie and returns the logout to the application.  However thats not really what its doing.  Its logging everyone out.

If we have three third party applications and one of them logs out then they will all be logged out because its the identity server thats getting logged out and not just the third party application.

I know for example that google does not allow third party logout.  I am currently logged in using my google account to SO and if i logout of that its only going to log me out of SO and not Google and all of my other applications logged into Google.

So my question is how do i prevent third party applications from logging everyone out and still allow them to log themselves out?

**What i have tried**

I tried doing a check that if the application calling the logout was one of our third party apps to just not remove the cookie.  That didnt work because they the application just checks the identity server again and says its still logged there needs to be a way for the third party apps to be logged out and only log back in when the user requests it.   I considered deleting the users consent but that wouldn't work either as they will have to grant consent again the next time they login.

**What i have considers**

I considered telling our third party developers that they need to have a dummy view with a login button on it so that users would have to click that button rather thank having them link directly to the login on the identity server.  I dont think this solution would be very popular with the developers though.

Comment: _its still logged there needs to be a way for the third party apps to be logged out and only log back in when the user requests it_ imho that's a problem with the implementation of the 3rd party app. The 3rd party app would need to show the user a login page telling him hes not logged in and a login-button (like the google and facebook login buttons) that redirects the user to the provider and not do an automatic redirect (when user access a site needs to be logged in for).

Comment: Alternatively, revoke/delete the users consent for the given application, then he will be asked on the next login if he wants to allow it. This however doesn't solve the issue of the 3rd party application redirecting him back and that the user then sees the consent page instead of being auto logged in :p

Comment: Yes thats exactly what i was thinking.  However I am not going to be popular if all of our third party applications suddenly cant logout until they add the login button idea.

Comment: Imho you (or app developer in general) should only do auto-redirect (without letting user click a button) a user to the IdentityProvider when there is a single auth provider (i.e. Azure services to Azure AD) ever and its a mandatory access the resource (i.e. accessing a SharePoint resource or Office 365). Applications triggering a single-sign out (which is what happens in your case) without asking (and telling) the user that he will be logged out of all services are generally considered a rude behavior

Comment: Typically, the user should be asked by the IdSrv if he wishes the logout, but this consent doesn't happen when the calling site sends a token hint. See the [docs](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/endpoints/endsession.html). It just means the 3rd party implementation is wrong (and rude) here and doing it without the users consent. You're on the stronger end though, if they don't comply, revoke their client ids, problem solved till they :P

Comment: P.S. for an application logout the 3rd party application doesn't need a round-trip to the IdentityProvider, just delete the 3rd parties cookie. But even deleting IdSrvs cookie (on sso) it shouldn't log out all other applications immediately (only once their tokes expire and need to be refreshed). A federated log-out also immediately logs you out of all other websites http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/signout.html#refsignout. If you don't want apps to be signed out via federated signout you should leave the signout urls empty on the client models

Comment: a good 80% of our third party apps are plugins they dont even have logout so its only an issue for the standalone applications.

Comment: The "await HttpContext.SignOutAsync();" can have a parameter (the cookie name).  You can't use a different name for each application? (I'm a newbie in authentication)

Comment: For something like StackOverflow they have their own cookies that are administered after the delegated authentication occurs from a third party. If you want to log out of stack overflow they just delete the cookies they made for you to access their site. That’s the reason I can go back to the login page, click sign in with a service like github, and not have to re-enter my dress. The end session endpoint does *not* need to be called here.if that’s what’s currently being done.

Comment: Looks like your 3rd party apps are using your cookie to keep their session and thats the main issue here. They need to keep their own session in their own cookie, which they kill on logout. Next time, cookie is not there, display login page, they go to IS4, and depending if your idsrv cookie is expired or deleted in the meanwhile your login page will be displayed or not. Google is good example of that behaviour. 
Keep note that all tokens issued (refresh and access) are still valid after their logout.